# List files changed with pattern and save them in a variable

Tags: makefile

Looking for a way to list files who have changed (the same way as it is possible with a target) but save this list into a variable.

Right know, i use this trick but i'm not really satisfied with it.

```
SPECS_CHANGED :=

$(GIF_PATH)/%.gif: $(TEST_SPEC_PATH)/%.rb
  $(eval SPECS_CHANGED := $(SPECS_CHANGED)$(notdir $(?:.rb=))|)
```

Is there a better method to achieve the same purpose without using a target ?

Regards,

Comment: That should not work at all, as `$(eval ...)` is expanded before `$?` is set. In fact, it's possible to achieve such result by using `$(shell ...)`, but I'm sure you'd better to re-think your project and to avoid this completely.

Comment: You're first sentence is not true.  The `eval` appears inside the recipe and all automatic variables, including `?`, are set before the recipe is expanded.